# CMake quoting problem

Tags: build, sed, makefile, cmake, quotes

I am trying to run `sed` from CMake. The problem is that CMake really messes up the expressions passed to `sed`. Here's a snippet from the `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
${SED_TOOL} -e "'1 s@.*@\#include \"config.hpp\"\\nnamespace LANG_NAMESPACE {\\nnamespace lexyacc {\\n\\n&@'" -e "'\$ s@.*@&\\n}}\\n@'"
```

And here's what CMake turns it into:

```
/bin/sed -e '1\ s@.*@#include\ "config.hpp"\nnamespace\ LANG_NAMESPACE\ {\nnamespace\ lexyacc\ {\n\n&@' -e '$\ s@.*@&\n}}\n@'
```

How should I fix this? And is there any good reference on how CMake's quoting works?

**EDIT: here's an example:**

http://pastebin.com/G9NRfrp7

http://pastebin.com/y9776Lt9

Comment: I added an example that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think you need the outer-most surrounding dbl-quote chars. Cmake is almost certainly passing the sed cmd to a shell, which then executes it. Putting the sed strings in dbl-quotes means some extra evaluation will be performed. Eliminate dbl-quotes, unless you need to have a variable evaluated, and then use something like

```
sed -e 's/xxx/yyy/;s/'"${var1}/${var2}"'/;s/www/zzz/'
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I used double-quotes because I somehow though that CMake could somehow mess up the whitespace in the expression or use it to separate arguments. Anyway, even with your suggestion, there are problems: CMake interprets the "#" in the expression as the beginning of a comment, and how do I escape backslashes so that there will be a single backslash in the makefile?

Comment: While there are rules for how this works, given 1. how complex expressions and the required multiple pass evaluations (i.e. Cmake->shell_1->?shell_n?->sed, etc.) AND 2. the relative infrequency of these sort of problems, I find it easiest to make tiny test cases for each piece that is giving me a problem. If you're lucky you'll only need 1 '\' char in fron of the '#', but I have had occasions where I've needed anywhere from 2 through 5 escape chars preceding, yes, '\\\\\' ! THE SAME for single backslash, possibly up to 5. Good Luck!

Comment: I tried it, and the problem is that it still puts backslashes before spaces, even if I don't use double quotes!

Comment: @mtk358 : been away most of the day. The examples on pastebin help alot. Can you post similar for the error messages you are getting?